# how to sort the bar chart values in python?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

the bars are not in order. Any advise on how to sort it ? the data is being sorted by review_count.

data as per below.

[image: bar chart]
[image: data]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(11,6))


grouped = df_graph1.groupby('New_zip_code')['review_count'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)[:10]
sns.barplot(grouped.index, grouped.values, palette=sns.color_palette("GnBu_r", len(grouped))) 

plt.xlabel('Zip code', labelpad=10, fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Count', fontsize=14)
plt.title('Count of Reviews by Zip Code (Top 10)', fontsize=15)
# plt.tick_params(labelsize=14)
# plt.xticks(rotation=15)
for  i, v in enumerate(grouped):
    plt.text(i, v*0.9, str(v), horizontalalignment ='center',fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)
```